# Move images when vertical scroll reaches certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, xhtml

Working on a website and wish to enlarge one image and move two others when the vertical scroll reaches the images, so they see the animation.

Example: https://www.xero.com/nz/ (scroll until you see the screenshots animate).

I believe this will require JS, but I have no idea. This is what I have so far...

```
style="left:240px; top:1460px; width:auto; height:auto; z-index:3" src="screen_01_500_325.png"
```

This image needs to enlarge from 500px wide to 600px. Height auto.

```
style="left:40px; top:1468px; width:auto; height:auto; z-index:2" src="screen_02_275_280.png"
```

This image needs to move from left:40px to left:0px. It stays the same size.

```
style="left:666px; top:1468px; width:auto; height:auto; z-index:2" src="screen_03_275_280.png"
```

This image need to move to the right from left:666px to left:706px. It stays the same size.

Basically I'd like the animation to occur when the person scrolls to 1400px down the page.

Thank you for your assistance. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Their animation is happening using JS. If you'd like I can post there JS code, and you could maybe apply it to your site.

Comment: Thank you @PhotographyBum. I'd love it if you could post the JS. I really have no idea and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that seems to be all related to the animation. I hope it helps.

```
!function() {
for (var e = 0, t = ["ms", "moz", "webkit", "o"], n = 0; n < t.length&&!window.requestAnimationFrame; ++n)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[t[n] + "RequestAnimationFrame"], window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[t[n] + "CancelAnimationFrame"] || window[t[n] + "CancelRequestAnimationFrame"];
window.requestAnimationFrame || (window.requestAnimationFrame = function(t) {
    var n = (new Date).getTime(), i = Math.max(0, 16 - (n - e)), o = window.setTimeout(function() {
        t(n + i)
    }, i);
    return e = n + i, o
}), window.cancelAnimationFrame || (window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(e) {
    clearTimeout(e)
})
}(), define("vendor/polyfills/requestanimationframe", function() {}), define("throttle-to-frame", ["vendor/polyfills/requestanimationframe"], function() {
"use strict";
function e(e, t) {
    function n() {
        var r = arguments;
        i = window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            i = null, e.apply(t, r), o && (n.apply(null, a), o=!1, a = null)
        })
    }
    var i, o=!1, a = null;
    return function() {
        return o ? void 0 : i ? (o=!0, void(a = arguments)) : void n.apply(null, arguments)
    }
}
return e
});
```

and

```
function() {
    if (Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms) {
        var t = e(".overview .animation");
        t.find(".animation__image--laptop").xscrollview().one("visible.xscrollview", function()  {
            t.addClass("animation--trigger")
        })
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot tonight. Looking at the code, it's not as easy to follow as I hoped (i.e. I thought there'd be reference to px offsets). I'll see what it does though and take it from there.